# Why does Fedora create /root with permissions `r-xr-x---`?

Tags: fedora, permissions, root, home

Are there any documents, which provide a reason for my `/root` being marked as not writeable by its owner?  (`r-xr-x---`)

I am aware that its owner would often have write access anyway, by virtue of  CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE.  However it still surprised me to see this.  So I'm  curious whether there is anything I can learn from it!

Debian's approach looks more natural to my eyes. On Debian, the permission is `rwx------`.

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /root
filesystem-3.2-37.fc24.x86_64
$ sudo dnf info filesystem | grep Release
Release     : 37.fc24
$ grep ^VERSION= /etc/os-release
VERSION="25 (Workstation Edition)"
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=517575

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was changed in Fedora around 2009.  Source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=517575P

Credit to @jordanm for pointing this out.  I have attempted to copy the relevant quotes.  Disclaimer: I'm sure this rendering has lost something in the process.

> The changes take away write permissions for root so that you also need DAC_OVERRIDE in order to write. We then dropped capabilities on things that needed to be root, but are network facing, or setuid.

### Critical response

> Anyways, this was a well-intentioned idea, but in reality it won't work without significant further work because a process with uid 0 but not CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE is still perfectly capable of rewriting e.g. /usr/bin/bash which still has u+w, or /root/.bashrc for that matter.  The answer to this sort of thing is SELinux.  Any objections to a patch to revert back to mode 755 for directories?

Answer from the author:

> What problem does [your software] have? If its trying to write to system directories, it should have a problem.

Reply:

> It's not a big deal, the code to effectively revert it rpm-ostree is small and shouldn't be hard to carry over time.
>
> I just wanted to cross-link the bugs so that anyone else who hit this can see the change we did in rpm-ostree.
>
> *Third party interjection: It's about kludges that are needed in any tool of the class to cope with this.*
>
> https://github.com/projectatomic/rpm-ostree/pull/335
>
> Link to the Fedora bug that introduced this, and also change things so
>   it's also used for the "compose" case because:
>
> - Again it doesn't add security
> - Tools that operate on "compose" repos have to work around this
>     when doing checkouts, see e.g. https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg-app/2016-June/000241.html